# How to distinct duplicated records in sql?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Hi I have two tables named ArtPlace and PhotoTable. i store places in artPlace table and their photos to photoTable and i pass Id of place as an ObjectId to PhotoTable.for any image that i record for a place it adds record with same ObjectId .when i want to retrieve the art place i want to get just one record;
here is my code sample and the result:

```
SELECT ArtPlace.Id ,
       PhotoTable.ObjectId,
       ArtPlace.ArtPlaceName,
       ArtPlace.Address,
       ArtPlace.Title,
       ArtPlace.Summary,
       ArtPlace.Description,
       ArtPlace.Visitor,
       ArtPlace.Website,
       PhotoTable.PhotoName
FROM ArtPlace
INNER JOIN City ON ArtPlace.CityId = City.Id
INNER JOIN PhotoTable ON( dbo.PhotoTable.ObjectId = dbo.ArtPlace.Id and dbo.PhotoTable.CategoryId = 5 )
WHERE ArtPlace.CityId = @CityId AND 
      dbo.ArtPlace.IsActive = 1 AND 
      dbo.PhotoTable.CategoryId = 5

END;
```

[here is the result: please click on it to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4EjK.png)
the only difference is in just photoName colunm

Comment: where is the result ??

Comment: please click on the link

Comment: Can't really tell from the image but are you not just after `SELECT DISTINCT`?

Comment: Distinct didn'n work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You query giving you correct result but if you want only one record then you can use ROW_NUMBER

```
;WITH CTE AS (
       SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ArtPlace.Id ORDER BY ArtPlace.Id) RN,
         ArtPlace.Id ,
         PhotoTable.ObjectId,
         ArtPlace.ArtPlaceName,
         ArtPlace.Address,
         ArtPlace.Title,
         ArtPlace.Summary,
         ArtPlace.Description,
         ArtPlace.Visitor,
         ArtPlace.Website,
         PhotoTable.PhotoName
     FROM ArtPlace
     INNER JOIN City ON ArtPlace.CityId = City.Id
     INNER JOIN PhotoTable ON dbo.PhotoTable.ObjectId = dbo.ArtPlace.Id
     WHERE ArtPlace.CityId = @CityId AND 
     dbo.ArtPlace.IsActive = 1 AND 
     dbo.PhotoTable.CategoryId = 5
  )
  SELECT * 
  FROM CTE
  WHERE RN=1
```

Comment: no i want just one of the duplicated records.in your suggestion i will have only one record

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here is the JOIN with the PhotoTable, because for each picture in that location it returns the rows with the location detail. My suggestion is to replace the join with an EXISTS clause and remove the PhotoTable.PhotoName and PhotoTable.ObjectId from the result set. This way you are looking at the locations only without any Photo details.

```
SELECT ArtPlace.Id ,
        ArtPlace.ArtPlaceName,
        ArtPlace.Address,
        ArtPlace.Title,
        ArtPlace.Summary,
        ArtPlace.Description,
        ArtPlace.Visitor,
        ArtPlace.Website
 FROM ArtPlace
      INNER JOIN City ON ArtPlace.CityId = City.Id
 WHERE ArtPlace.CityId = @CityId
       AND dbo.ArtPlace.IsActive = 1
       AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM PhotoTable WHERE dbo.PhotoTable.ObjectId = dbo.ArtPlace.Id and dbo.PhotoTable.CategoryId = 5 )
```

Also I would suggest to remove the hardcoding of CategoryId = 5 and make it a param with a default value if it's not possible to have it a pure parameter.

Comment: i want to show the photo in my website too .i can't remove it

Comment: In that case you do not have any duplicates since each photo is unique, right?

Comment: What are you looking to achieve here? Maybe you are looking for 2 result sets, 1 with locations and 1 with photos?

Comment: i just want one of the duplicated records

Comment: But we have just established that you do not have any duplicates because each photo name is unique. Do you want to have just 1 photo per location returned?